# FileNotFoundException running NUnit

Tags: nunit, filenotfoundexception

I encountered a FileNotFoundException when running some tests in Visual Studio via Resharper.  So I decided to go back and check running the NUnit GUI.  The first thing I tried was to make sure everything was working properly and ran the NUnit tests that came with the NUnit install (NunitTests.nunit).

Most passed, but there were quite a few tests that failed.  There appears to be two main failures:

> NUnit.Util.Tests.ProcessRunnerTests.BasicRunnerTests.CountTestCases:
>   System.ArgumentException : NUnit components for version 2.0.50727.3615 of the CLR are not installed
>   Parameter name: targetRuntime

and

> NUnit.Util.Tests.RemoteTestResultTest.ResultStillValidAfterDomainUnload:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.core.interfaces, Version=2.5.9.10348, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This is NUnit 2.5.9 installed using the msi and the nunit.core.interfaces.dll does exist.  I added it's location to the system path but that didn't help.

Is there something else that needs to be configured for NUnit to work properly?  Not sure if my original problem is related to this, but it seems like I need to at least get these baseline tests to work first.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this it was for v2.5.10.  I found that I had not actually referenced nunit.core.interfaces.dll in my dependencies folder as well.

I ended up having 3 references:

- unuit.core.dll
- nunit.core.interfaces.dll
- nunit.framework.dll

hope this might help.